Extract Nested Json String from Mongodb C#
  {
    "property_1": "value_1",
    "property_2": "value_2",
    "property_3": {
      "_some_property_1": 1,
      "_some_property_2": "some_value_2",
      "some_property_3": "some_value_3",
      "some_property_4": "some_value_4"
    },
    "property_4": "value_4",
    "property_5": "value_5",
    "iproperty_6": "Nvalue_6",
    "property_7": "value_7",
    "property_8": "value_8",
    "property_9": "value_9"
  }

this is one of the field of my document I want to extract some fields from property_3 using MongoDb Aggregation Pipeline .I have stored the whole json in string format. I want to perform it in pipeline itself.
I tried doing using 2 stages converting the field to JObject but failed

My guess is that you'll need a JavaScript function (see this question). Also see docs.

MongoDB C# Driver BsonSerializer doesn't know how to convert to JObject as JObject is from Newtonsoft.Json. So you can't include JObject in the aggregation pipeline. But, after getting the query result, you can apply converting the string to JObject. Since you are not providing the attempt, it will be hard to provide the actual solution and only able to guide you for the direction.
